# How to select first number within a cell for the "criteria1" of SUMIFS in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2011, vba

I'm using SUMIFS(), and I want the criteria1 to be the first number of a series of comma separated numbers within a cell. For example,

```
A1=1111, 1112  SUMIFS(B:B, C:C, A1)
```

So basically, the formula should add all the cells in B:B that are adjacent to each cell in C:C that has the value "1111", but I don't know how to specify to the function to use 1111, but ignore 1112.  Its one of those syntax rules that only expert Excel users know about. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to parse the data:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B, C:C, TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)))
```

Comment: Parse! Thats what its called!  Thank you!!